# How to get sender profile image from quickblox in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, quickblox

I am using QBChatMessage to get all messages sent in the chat.

I have uploaded the user's image in admin panel of quickblox. Now, i am facing problem in getting the image from quickblox contents.

If anyone knows, please help me. 
As I have already tried getting the user image using message.senderID but it is not succeeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this approach? First of all you should get user by id, and then check his `avatarURl` and `blobID`

```
        QBRequest.userWithID(message.senderID, successBlock: { (response :QBResponse?, user:QBUUser?) in

        if user?.avatarUrl == nil {

            //no avatar. Download file by user's blob id
            let userProfileBlobUID = user?.blobID
            QBRequest.downloadFileWithID(UInt(userProfileBlobUID!), successBlock: { (response : QBResponse,imageData: NSData) in

                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)

                }, statusBlock: nil, errorBlock: nil)
        }
        else {
            //download image by url
        }

    }) { (response :QBResponse) in

    }
```

Comment: I already got the solution and it is same answer which is worked. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Guru Please tell me that where to paste this code?

Comment: @Guru: is messge QBChatDialog Object ?

Comment: I have successfully updated the image for a user I can after upload I could get a public image url(contains image). But in the chat list page. I was trying to display as per above got eroor '[QBResponse], status: 404"